# Crossfit distance, how reliable is it?

Tags: running, jogging, walking, crossfit

First of all I'd like to say that I'm extremely unfit, with me being 5"10 and weighing in at 125kg. I am trying to get fit enough to go on a skiing trip with some friends at work in February so I've started to do around 10 mins(5 mins of which is just warm up exercises) of exercise most days a week on a crossfit trainer. As such I'm wondering what kind of goals i should be setting myself on the crossfit trainer and how comparable they are to walking/running. I have read online that the distance crossfit trainers show are more lenient than more natural exercises so I am unsure whether my current pace of 1.2km in 5 mins on the crossfit trainer is actually comparable to the same pace walking/jogging/running.

Does anyone know how much leeway I should give to this pace so I can more accurately compare to a person doing their pace off the machine?

I also feel a lot of the work being done towards the front of my legs and am worried that I'm not working all my muscles. I don't really have that good a balance on this machine so I feel I lean into the machine more than I should. Is this something I should be concerned about?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First off I wouldn't say that 10 mins is enough to be getting fit and losing weight. You will develop balance over time and fitness no matter what exercises you do. Working muscles more than others is natural.

Comment: Yeah, I plan to increase the time on the machine over the next couple of months. I was going to increase it in increments of 20% which should have me doing 1hr and 32 mins by the time I'm leaving. I should probably start with more but as I said I'm extremely unfit, I couldn't walk last week after doing 10 mins on the machine.

Comment: I would recommend not going over an hour every single day. But instead increase intensity on some days then do longer sessions on other days. Keep a mixture to increase your progression. But yes, I would keep going with that plan and good luck :0

Comment: The trainer is probably inaccurate, but the test is easy:  go outside and walk/run at about the same level of excursion for 1.2km.  See how long it takes.  Also, being that you are working up to a level of fitness.  Why not do a 10min session in the morning and a second one in the later afternoon/early evening.  That way you can get twice the workout in, but also have recovery time.

Answer (score 1):

great to see you trying to get fit. i have a friend who was quite over weight. we started very low intensity workouts for 20 minutes each day. take it slow. after the second week he felt that he could increase our workouts so we increased the intensity for a further 2 weeks. we then increased the time spent in each workout. small daily workouts are better than 1 or 2 workouts per week that are longer. the other aspect that you should also look at is your diet. that is a massive contributor. lower your sugar intake if you can.